# Batch file to delete *.vcproj.* e.g. code.vcproj.user1 but no *.vcproj

Tags: batch-file, vcproj

how to write a batch file to delete VisualStudioUserFile (`*.vcproj.*`) only but not the VisualStudioProject (`*.vcproj`)?

Answer (score 1):

This can be run interactively in `cmd`:

```
for %x in (*.vcproj.*) do if not "%~xx"==".vcproj" del "%x"
```

if you want a batch file, then you need

```
for %%x in (*.vcproj.*) do if not "%%~xx"==".vcproj" del "%%x"
```

This won't delete files like `blah.vcproj.vcproj`, though. I don't know how likely those are in your case.